# How do you change text color in LibreOffice Impress?

Tags: libreoffice, presentation

How do I change slide text color?

I don't see a format text menu ribbon like I am accustomed to seeing in Microsoft Powerpoint, nor do I see a collection of text editing options like in Google Documents.

Comment: I do not see where the text color is displayed in the toolbar, so I am unable to follow the instruction at https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Changing_the_Color_of_Text I have already tried Line Color and Fill Color, and neither of these change the text color.

Answer (score 6):

Found via searching menu bar Help > LibreOffice Help for 'color': Click View > Toolbars > Color Bar (scroll down; it is not alphabetized but rather at the bottom of the list), then with the text highlighted, click on the desired color panel in the bottom Color Bar (panel that appears beneath the slide).

Comment: this is not the best design decision by whoever designed libreoffice draw .

Comment: I think the developers need to sit down with the users and have a discussion.

Comment: "Color bar" toolbar does not exist anymore (or at least in my version). On the upside, the list does seem sorted. I had to use the "text formatting" toolbar as mentioned in @RudyF 's answer

Comment: Cowboy developers...

Answer (score 5):

You can also add the "Text Formatting" toolbar to get access to all text formatting options. View > Toolbars > Text Formatting.

Sorry, LibreOffice, but this is quite non-intuitive (i.e. dumb). When one highlights text, the text formatting toolbar should automatically appear. No?

Comment: This is a best answer. But the panel will hide as soon as you select a non-text element. So, you will have to add it as a third panel, and it will show up when you edit text.
Another way is to select a text, right click on it and choose "Characters" (or "symbols"). Then you can change the color on the "Fonts Effect" tab:
https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/draw-how-to-change-text-color/54772

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I ended up here by searching "libreoffice impress font color formula", so there is my solution for coloring the Formula-Text

You can use coloring in your ormula by using the `color` tag:

```
color <color> {your math expression}
```

I wasn't able to use hex-Color-Codes, but only words, like

```
white black red green blue
```

There might be more usable colors.

I found it in the OpenOffice-Forum, but it works in LibreOffice too:

https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=11835